# AEM 6.5 startup issue

Tags: aem

The AEM server goes into state "startup in progress". After all the workaround suggested in the community, nothing worked. Had to restore the backup. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There can be many reasons for this. Without entries from the error.log and/or the stdout.log, it is difficult to help. For example, AEM was shutdown abrubtly and got corrupted, or the server was started with root and then it was started with a dedicated user, code was deployed and the bundles are causing a lot of dependencies issues, etc.